# Bat file to create & write to a file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I'm trying to create and write to a file using .bat

```
@echo off

echo Jackdows loves my big sphinx >> %appdata%\data.html
echo Of quartz. >> %appdata%\data.html

exit
```

Works properly. However, if user runs it again, it writes the same values to the file again. So in the files, there are multiple values. Is it possible to prevent this ?

Comment: Change the first redirect to a single `>` chevron to clear out the existing values of the file.  Else if you want to preserve the contents of the file, you will need to check if your lines already exist in the file using the `find` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>>` appends text to a file regardless of whether it exists elsewhere in the file or not. You can, however, search the file first for the string and then only append the line if it does not already exist.

```
@echo off

:: Appends a string to a file only if that string is not present in that file
call :ainp "Jackdaws love my big sphinx" text.txt
call :ainp "Of quartz" text.txt
call :ainp "Rule Brittania" text.txt

exit /b

:: Append If Not Present
:AINP
set "search_string=%~1"
set "search_file=%~2"

>nul find "%search_string%" %search_file%
if %errorlevel% equ 1 (
    >>%search_file% echo %search_string%
)
```

Comment: Only writes the first line

Comment: I just ran it. It creates the file in the same path where you run the script.

Comment: Also, if the other lines are anywhere else in the file already, they won't be added. Check the file and see if the lines exist.